# Find spatial discontinuities in r

Tags: r, spatial

I would like to draw previously unknown borders based on spatial discontinuities, i.e. a significant change in the value of a variable of interest between adjacent points.

I have tried sm.discontinuity with geographic coordinates, but found the border to be changing a lot.

Points are generated with code below.

```
set.seed(2)

scatter = data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100, mean = 1.5, sd = .6),
  y = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 2),
  value = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 2)
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What counts as a significant change?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Allan, significant in a RDD and/or a large difference (e.g. 1 s.d.) between neighboring points.